# Joomla 1.6 textarea extended custom field not working and appearing as a text(input instead of textarea)

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7, joomla1.6

first cusrom field file-
StepDescription.php

```
 <?php

    /*
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    jimport('joomla.form.helper');
    JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('textarea');

    /**
     * Description of StepTitle
     *
     * @author admin
     */
    class JFormFieldStepDescription extends JFormFieldTextarea {

        public $type = 'StepDescription';

        function getLabel() {
            return parent::getLabel();
        }

        function getInput() {
            $this->name .= '[]';


            if (empty($this->value)) {
                $this->value = '';
                return parent::getInput();
            } else {
                $arr = array();
                $values = $this->value;
                $this->value = null;
                foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
                    $this->value = $value;
                    $arr[] = parent::getInput();
                }
                return $arr;
            }
        }

    }
```

second custom field file-
StepTitle.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
jimport('joomla.form.helper');
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('text');

/**
 * Description of StepTitle
 *
 * @author admin
 */
class JFormFieldStepTitle extends JFormFieldText {

    function getLabel() {
        return parent::getLabel();
    }

    function getInput() {
        $this->name .= '[]';
        if (empty($this->value)) {
            $this->value = '';
            return parent::getInput();
        } else {
            $arr = array();
            foreach ($this->value as $key => $value) {
                $this->value = $value;
                $arr[] = parent::getInput();
            }
            return $arr;
        }
    }

}
```

here is the form i am using
content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- $Id: login.xml 22059 2011-09-10 05:20:13Z infograf768 $ -->
<form>
    <fieldset name="content"
              label="Content"   
    >

        <field name="jobname" type="text"
               label="Job name"
               size="25"
               class="inputbox jobname"
               required="true"
        />
        <field name="projectortip" type="list"
               label="Project or Tip" 
               class="selectbox"
               required="true"
        >
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Project</option>
            <option value="2">Tip</option>
        </field>
        <field name="costestimate" type="text"
               label="Cost estimate"            
               size="25"
               class="inputbox"
        />
        <field name="category" type="list"
               label="Category"
               class="selectbox"
               required="true"
        >
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1">cat1</option>
            <option value="2">cat2</option>
        </field>

        <field name="timetaken" type="text"
               label="Time Taken"
               size="25"
               class="inputbox"
        />
        <field name="comment" type="checkbox"
               label="Allow members to make comments"
               default = "false"
               class="checkbox"
        />
        <field name="difficultylevel" type="list"
               label="Difficulty Level"
               class="selectbox"
               required="true"
        >
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1">easy</option>
            <option value="2">medium</option>
            <option value="3">hard</option>
        </field>
        <field name="emailcomment" type="checkbox"
               label="Email me all member comments"         
               default = "false"
               class="checkbox" 
        />
        <field name="metadata" type="textarea"
               label="Metadata"     
               class="textarea"
        />
        <field name="background_information" type="textarea"
               label="Background Information"
               class="textarea"
        />
        <field name="tools_used" type="textarea"
               label="Tools Used"
               class="textarea"
        />
        <field name="material_used" type="textarea"
               label="Material Used"
               class="textarea"
        />

    </fieldset>
        <fieldset name="step" label="Step" >

        <field name="step_title" type="StepTitle"
               label="Step Title"
               required="true"
               class="step_title"
        />
        <field name="step_description" type="StepDescription"
               label="Step Description" 
               class="step_description"
               required="true"
        />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <field name="id" type="hidden" />
        <field name="return" type="hidden" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

StepTitle is inputbox and StepDescription is textarea but both StepTitle and StepDescription are displayed as a inputbox in frontend component form. And this problem is not in local but only when i use these same files on server.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with file name. StepTitle.php and StepDescription works in localhost in windows machine, but in linux server file name must be in smallcase. so smallcase filenames like steptitle.php and stepdescription.php  solved my problem.